# How to return '£' in RESTfull web services as stream

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, c#-4.0, wcf-rest

I'm developing a RESTfull web services using WCF. In this service I'm returning a XML in Stream format which contains '£'. I get this in symbol in XML but on client side I get the '?' instead of '£'.

```
public Stream HandleMessageStream()
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request);
            string text = "<price>£ 10.00</price>";
            UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(text));
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/html";
            return ms;
        }
```

I tried with different encoding but didn't find the answer.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: You could try to encode the pound sign as &pound; or &#163; .

Comment: Try to set `text/html; charset="utf-8"` to *ContentType*

Comment: How is the client reading the data?  If it doesn't know it's UTF-8 then that is the source of your problem.  I4V's suggestion may fix the problem, if the client interprets the content type properly.

Comment: None of the above suggestions are working

Comment: I'm using 'Send HTTP Tool' to call the method of the service. In that I'm checking the output returned.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using

> Server.HtmlEncode ?

```
string text = Server.HtmlEncode("<price>£ 10.00</price>");
```

Comment: Just encode the part you need to encode, and then use the Server.HtmlDecode

Comment: What is the namespace for Server.HtmlEncode method. I'm not getting that. I'm coding in a WCFServiceLibrary class.